# Discussion continued as chat disappears

Tags: discussion

I ask a question:

[Is Top provably not cartesian closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123950/is-top-provably-not-cartesian-closed)

and get a very helpful answer. But I also get a not very helpful exchange of comments. I get invited to continue this exchange as chat, and I accept the invitation. A few weeks later my reply on chat has disappeared. This doesn't seem to be a satisfactory resolution to the exchange of comments.

Comment: I cannot see [the discussion continued in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2894/discussion-between-rob-arthan-and-zhen-lin). What about this situation is unsatisfactory? Also, I noticed that you accepted an (the) answer to the question.

Comment: That's the point - I was very happy with the answer but not with the unhelpful comments. I did continue the discussion as chat, but all trace of that has disappeared, leaving just a trail of comments that keeps suggesting there is something incorrect in my question, with no resolution.

Comment: Well, if this has been resolved in chat, you could ask the other person to delete the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chat rooms are automatically deleted if they don't have a minimum amount of messages in them. I don't remember the exact amount, but I think your room is just slightly below the required number.

Comment: I am sure that is the explanation. If I had known that is how it works, I would have moved to chat after the very first unhelpful comment.